# how to change the header title for featured product module in opencart

Tags: php, opencart

- i added multiple featured module in homepage. so,i need to change the header title for that
- Example:
- featuredproducts.
- featuredproducts.
- i want to change the title featuredproducts into promotions for 2nd module only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change that into your tpl file ...